# Why does Block use struct __Block_byref_object_0 instead of a single pointer to capture a variable decorated with "__block"

Tags: objective-c, clang, objective-c-blocks

Here is my source code in file main.m

```
 __block NSInteger blockInteger = 123;
 static NSInteger staticInteger = 123;
 void (^testBlock)(void) = ^() {
     blockInteger++;
     staticInteger++;
     NSLog(@"%ld", blockInteger);
     NSLog(@"%ld", staticInteger);
 };
 testBlock();
```

When I used clang command "clang -rewrite-objc main.m", I got this

```
struct __Block_byref_blockInteger_0 {
   void *__isa;
   __Block_byref_blockInteger_0 *__forwarding;
   int __flags;
   int __size;
   NSInteger blockInteger;
};
struct __main_block_impl_0 {
   struct __block_impl impl;
   struct __main_block_desc_0* Desc;
   NSInteger *staticInteger;
   __Block_byref_blockInteger_0 *blockInteger; // by ref
   ...
};
```

I am wondering why block use __Block_byref_blockInteger_0 to capture blockInteger since it use a NSInteger pointer to capture a static variable . What does __Block_byref_blockInteger_0 exactly do? What are the advantages of this struct by comparing with a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is creating a number of structures to help the block refer to its "enclosed" values. (Remember that a block makes a copy of, or "encloses", all of the values that are outside the block, which is why blocks are also called "closures".)

So the first structure (`__Block_byref_blockInteger_0`) is creating an object to encapsulate the `blockInteger` automatic. This is because automatic variables disappear at the end of the function, but blocks must be able to refer to them long afterwards.

The second structure encapsulates all of the values (including `__Block_byref_blockInteger_0`) that are being "captured" by the block. This give the block a single reference to all of its enclosed values, copied when the block was created.

Now the `NSInteger *staticInteger` instance value is a bit of an odd duck, since the address of the global `staticInteger` can't change. But that's a pretty minor difference as it's still just a copy of an address; whether that address can change is immaterial.

I suspect it's because of name scope; a static declared inside a function has a symbol scope limited to that function. And if you look at the compiler output, you'll see that every block you declare creates an invisible static function to contain its code. Since that second static function wouldn't normally be able to reference a static declared within another function, making a copy of the static's address is the only way for the block function to access it.